# ActivePDF Rest API consuming with Coldfusion

Tags: http, curl, coldfusion

ActivePDF started offering a REST API for converting documents to PDF files. We have used their .NET API for a while but now we want to try the REST. Unfortunately, there is almost no information about the REST API. On their website, there is single .net example which does not help much.

There is also a cURL command (no explanations on that on their website) but I assume it does the same - converts a supported file to PDF:

```
curl http://localhost:62625/api/DocConverter/Conversion -H "Authorization: Bearer [access token]" -F "InputFile=@c:/path/input.tif" -F "OutputFile=output.pdf" -F "DocConverterType=0" -F "PDFVersion=2" -F "MetadataAuthor=PDF Author" -F "Linearize=0" -F "UseMRC=2" -L -O -J
```

Anybody, have the expertise to convert this into cfhttp ColdFusion statement or have done REST with ActivePDF to give me some pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the [curl manual](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) to see what the various parameters mean. Most of them are form fields `-F "FieldName=value"` which usually become `<cfhttpparam name="FieldName" value="FieldValue">`. Give it a shot and post back if you have problems.

Comment: I tried that but had no luck. I'm hoping someone that have done that with activePDF can give me some pointers because activePDF support is pretty clueless.

Comment: It'll be easier for others to help if you the code you tried - and the result.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that activePDF REST API was buggy. After we contacted them and they acknowledged that the problem was in their software,then they came up with a fix. After the fix, all "fancy" code I wrote was meaningless.

This is the end/working result:

```
<cfhttp method="POST" url="#wURL#" result="LOCAL.wResult" timeout="60" multipart="true" multipartType="form-data">
    <cfhttpparam type="file" name="if1" file="#LOCAL.wInputFile#">
</cfhttp>
```